# $Re(z\overline{w}) = |z||w| \iff arg(w) = arg(z)\pm2k\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I need to prove:

$Re(z\overline{w}) = |z||w| \iff arg(w) = arg(z)\pm2k\pi$

So that's what I did:
 $$z = |z|(\cos \theta_1 + i\sin\theta_1)$$
 $$w = |w|(\cos \theta_2 + i\sin\theta_2)$$

$$z\overline{w} = |z|(\cos \theta_1 + i\sin\theta_1)|w|(\cos \theta_2 - i\sin\theta_2) = $$

$$|z||w|(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 -i\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2+i\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2) = $$

$$|z||w|(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 +\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2) + i(\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2)\rightarrow$$

$$Re(z\overline{w}) = |z||w|(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 +\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2) = |z||w|\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$

Mas $Re(z\overline{w}) = 0 \iff |z||w|\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) = 0 \iff \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) = 0 \iff $

but how to finish it? I'm not getting $z\pm 2k\pi$

Comment: $ \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1 $

Comment: It seems you assume $|z| = |w| = 1$. Maybe it is better to write $z = r_1 e^{i \theta_1}, w = r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$, and consider separately the cases $r_1 =0$, $r_2 = 0$.

Comment: @sometempname could you take a look? I updated

Comment: I think you want $\cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = 1$. Also notice $\arg z$ is not well-defined if $z=0$.

Comment: When is cosine equal to zero? When the input is an integer multiple of $2\pi$. So we conclude $\theta_1-\theta_2=2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Then move $\theta_2$ to the other side.